# run( ) on terminated state thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been trying to find a reason why "execute" is only being printed once. But could not find an answer in the book I'm actually reading, [Java Threads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007825) or googling.

```
public void init(){
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("executed");
        }
    });
    t.start();
    while(true){
        if(!t.isAlive())
            t.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the JDK source code, here's the definition of `Thread.run()`:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

When you initiate the thread with a `Runnable` it gets set as the `target`. But when the thread is finished running, the system calls `exit()` on it, which, among other things, does:

```
target = null;
```

So the one `"executed"` you are seeing is from the `Thread` itself; by the time you call `run()` on the thread, `target` has been nullified, and `run()` does nothing.

Comment: So how do I implement it in order to execute run multiple times after a thread finish executing the run method for the first time?

Comment: @Nicolas because you do nonsense in your example, it is difficult to say. I do not understand what your are trying to achieve. Do you want to execute `run` once in a parallel thread and other times in the main (parent) thread? BTW, there is `thread.join()` method to wait unitl another thread terminated. Using `isAlive()` in busy-wait must not be used in production code.

Comment: @Val I am only trying to understand how threads work. I have just began dealing with the topic

Comment: @Nicolas You should understand that `thread.run` does not relive the thread, you do not ask another thread to execute any code this way. What `thread.run()` does is executing the `run` method directly, by means of your current thread as if it is an ordinary method, like any other. If you want to launch a parallel thread, you use `thread.start()`.

Comment: @Nicolas, you might try using a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` and each time you want to run your `Runnable` you can just `submit()` it to the service.